# Математическая задачка

Tags: математика

Здравствуйте.
Такой вопрос. Не программирование - просто математика.
Задача:
есть n количество людей. есть общий денежный фонд $, который делится на количество людей $/n. каждому человеку по совокупности критериев выставляется коэффициент (0.988, 0.554) (сумма коэффициентов не равна 100%). Вопрос: как между всеми людьми разделить деньги без остатка в зависимости от коэффициентов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О, это можно сделать достаточно просто =)

Если обозначить коэффициенты как a1, a2, ..., an, а бюджет - S, то i-му человеку достанется

```
(ai*S)/(a1+a2+...+an)
```

часть всех денег =)